# Cross-browser compatibility width issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser

[this site](http://www.dlalaw.com) has been giving me some issues with the width of some elements with cross-browser compatibility for the tablet and phone styling.

The class is `.p_phone`and `.p_phone a`

```
  .p_phone {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 145px;
    left: 40%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -4px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }

  .p_phone a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1968a1;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Basically, It needs to match the width of this class, which is a image, which it does on chrome and opera, but on safari, firefox, and edge, it does not match, and breaks to the next line.

```
  .p_call {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    top: -13px;
    left: 40%;
    width: 145px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(http://dchna4xuxekpx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/15142416/call-us.png);
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Increasing the width to 150px fixes it, but it is then too wide for the image.

How it needs to be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing these class's (have checked them on this [link provided by you](http://www.dlalaw.com/))

```
.textwidget {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  margin: auto;
}
.p_call {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  top: -13px;
  left: 40%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://dchna4xuxekpx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/15142416/call-us.png');
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.p_phone {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 40%;
}
.p_phone a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1968A1;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The divs belonging to `p_call` class and `p_phone` were not wrapped properly by `textwidget` class. Hence we have to give two different width's, now since `textwidget` is wrapping both the class's, they will have same width. Hope it helps. Tested on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: That did the job! I had to add additional padding and reduce the font size, but the result looks exactly how the client's mockup looked. Your a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your styling block for .p_phone a:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Fixed the issue on edge, introduced a new issue on safari(gets pushed to the right of the image it is supposed to be under) and fixed it in firefox. firefox width is a hair too wide now though. I believe it has to do with the way font is rendered in each browser.

Comment: Thanks! This, when combined with Hitesh's answer produced the results I needed!